# Can I change the Thread Affinity (Dispatcher) of a Control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I want to create a control which takes a while to create (Pivot) and then add it to the visual tree. To do this i would need to change the dispatcher of the control (and its heirachy) before adding it to the VisualTree.

Is this possible? Are there any implications of walking the controls trees and setting the _dispatcher field via reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this only works with Freezable derived classes. The best solution I see is to create the control on the UI Thread and show a progress bar during creation. To make this possible you will have to create the control in portions an let the progress bar update itself once in a while. This not only necessary for the progressbar but also will make sure that you application does not block.

Pseudocode (execure in extra thread):

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(UpdateProgress(0));
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(bigControlBuilder.Build(0,25));
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(UpdateProgress(25));
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(bigControlBuilder.Build(25,50));
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(UpdateProgress(50));
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(bigControlBuilder.Build(50,75));
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(UpdateProgress(75));
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(bigControlBuilder.Build(75,100));
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(UpdateProgress(100));
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(this.Children.Add(bigControlBuilder.GetControl()));
```

Update:

To make complex control more responsive you could also try UI-Virtualization/Data-Virtualisation:

Only load and show those visual items of the data items that are currently visible to ther user. Do not load and show visual items that are scrolled offscreen are to small to see or are in any other way invisible to the user. Upon userinteraction unload items that become invisble, load items that become visible.

Comment: That only works if you control the control being built. We are looking at ways of making a commercial Pivot control more responsive, or at least controlled by another thread.

Comment: No, the above code can also be **part** of your pivot control. Adding the many subitems to the Pivot (from the bound data) in portions.

Comment: Have marked as answer, I have tried a lot of hacks and nothing seems to work. The pivot control is not ours to control when the subitems get added. We could try adding to the ItemSource enumerable in chunks

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I suppose it is *possible* to set _dispatcher using reflection but I would not recommend it at all. There is a deeply ingrained notion in WPF of thread affinity and STA so I wouldn't mess with that.

bitbonk's approach is a good one.
Another approach we have used in a project of ours was to create a second UI thread and have a progress indicator be rendered by the second UI thread while the first UI thread is building the UI. As long as the progress bar stays in the visual tree owned by the second UI thread, you should be good.